# Is it possible to find a correlation coefficient in this situation?

Tags: correlation, biostatistics

I am new to statistics. I have a list of coyote sightings and am trying to figure out if the moon illumination percentage on that particular night is correlated to the sighting. Meaning, if the moon has a higher percentage of illumination, does that relate to an increased chance of a sighting happening or vice versa. Is it possible to find a correlation coefficient for this potential relationship?

Comment: Yes. Are you asking how? You'll need to provide an example of the type of data that you have (a reproducible example is ideal) https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have measurements of illuminance? Otherwise maybe there is historical data on cloud cover and stage of moon cycle.

Comment: can you provide eg a graph of the data. a correlation coefficient relates to a linear relationship - 100 times more light 100 times more sightings.

Comment: "*100 times more light 100 times more sightings.*" Notwithstanding a change of variables (e.g. log transform), yes. I've read that some human senses (e.g. [Fechner's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law#:~:text=Fechner%27s%20law%20states%20that%20the,with%20an%20accurate%20nonhuman%20instrument.)) are logarithmic. Linear models are only guaranteed to be linear in their parameters, not their predictors.

Comment: @Galen That applies to things like reaction times, motor control (see the literature on how people use mice, for instance) and, to some extent, to light sensitivity.  But, at the very least, these sitings will be related to *coyote* behavior, too.  Thus it would be wise not to approach the analysis with a simple theory in mind but rather to display and view the data in useful, meaningful ways to see whether and what relationships might hold.  Correlation coefficients can come later (if at all).

Comment: @whuber We agree it is unwise to rigidly restrict our models according to a simple (if not simplistic) theory. I tend to follow [*Bayesian Workflow*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01808) which involves starting with simple models and working up to more complex ones often by composing the simpler ideas together. I also tend to alternate between theorizing and plotting, starting with theory first. I find it valuable to iteratively brainstorm/read and then visually test my/other's thinking against plots. A bit subjective, but I feel I learn more and produce better models this way.

Comment: Also, 100% agree that correlation coefficients can come later (if at all).

Answer (score 2):

##### Some Answers

As direct answers to your questions...

> Is it possible to find a correlation coefficient for this potential relationship?

This is certainly so given these are both numeric variables, though it depends on what the data looks like. If your data is fairly linear, you should consider something like a Pearson $r$ coefficient, whereas if it behaves in a monotonic fashion, you should instead think of using something like Spearman's $\rho$ coefficient. The choice of correlation will depend on how the data is shaped.

> If the moon has a higher percentage of illumination, does that relate to an increased chance of a sighting happening or vice versa?

It could, but that's only known after you get your data. However, we can't really assign causality to either direction of this relationship given it is bivariate and can be tainted by any number of factors related to confounds, cross-sectional behavior, and other influences. You can see some of these issues are present in the comments, where the other users mention complexity of models. I highlight how this relates to regression in [a recent answer here,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626061/how-can-i-interpret-it-when-correlation-between-two-variables-is-significant-bu/626079#626079) as some variables have unexpected relationships that shape their associations with each other.

##### Potential Avenue of Exploration

If you are familiar with R at all, there is an [excellent episode](https://www.youtube.com/live/hG0ILWaVnH4?si=5FHs0B_8-8ijWaDY) from Tidy Tuesdays that analyzes Sasquatch sightings that may give you some relevant insight on what kind of data you could collect and what it may look like (such as timelines of sightings, seasonal distributions, text analysis of eyewitness testimony, etc.). As an example, I recall one part was where they looked at location by season differences in sightings, where there were some interesting communalities and uniqueness to each location.

[image]

Obviously the assumptions with that kind of data are as interesting as they are loaded with confounding influences. Are the sightings due to chance? Does location play a role? What alternative explanations can there be to each relationship? This may build some insight into your own project, as they both deal with encounters in the wild and provide some angles you haven't considered yet, particularly what extraneous variables may be shaping the relationships in these sightings.